# How do I refer to ASP.NET Controls in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm working on My First ASP.NET Application. I have created some text boxes and buttons, and added client-side validation to the text boxes. I now wish to set and clear the enabled property of the buttons according to the contents and validity of the text boxes.

I have studied the questions and answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155508/user-controls-in-asp-net-prefixing-string-to-child-controls-causing-problem-to-re), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384867/properly-referencing-controls-in-asp-net-user-controls-in-javascript), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246595/grabbing-asp-net-controls-in-javascript) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112274/refering-to-controls-through-javascript-function), and the best I have been able to manage is this...

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function SetButtonSensitivity()
    {
        var label = document.getElementById("<%= lblResult3.ClientID %>");
        var button = document.getElementById("<%= btnDone.ClientID %>");

        if (Page_ClientValidate())
        {
            label.Text = "valid";
            button.disabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            label.Text = "not valid";
            button.disabled = true;
        }

    }
</script>
```

I can tell this script is invoked when I tab away from the textbox fields, as the error messages are emitted by the client-validate, but the script has no effect on the button or the label.

Can anyone see what I have overlooked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't acces the Text property of a label from javascript.
A label is rendered as a . You should try setting the innerHTML property:

```
label.innerHTML = "not valid";
```

Also use the javascript console to see what errors you have in your js code. (Ctrl+Shift+J in firefox)

Answer (score 0):

Try `value` attribute instead of `Text`

```
label.value = "valid";
button.disabled = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, since your `Label` is actually rendered as a `<span>`
`label.innerText = "valid"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

label.innerHTML, label.innerText or label.value to get or set the text of the label.

"button.disabled = false/true" should work.